# How to Load external Div that has a dynamic content using ajax and jsp/servlets?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I need to use ajax feature to load an external div element (an external jsp file)  into the current page. That JSP page contains a **dynamic content** - e.g. content that is based on values received from the current session.

I solved this problem somehow, but I'm in doubt because I think that my solution is bad , or maybe there is better solution since I'm not expert.

I have three files:

- Javascript function that is triggered when a **TR** element is clicked, it requests html data from a servlet:

  ```
  $("#inboxtable tbody tr").click(function(){

      var trID = $(this).attr('id');
      $.post("event?view=read",{id:trID}, function(data){
          $("#eventContent").html(data); // load external file
      },"html"); // type

  });
  ```
- The servlet "event" loads the data and generates HTML content using **include** method :

  ```
  String id = request.getParameter("id");
  if (id != null) {
     v.add("Test");
     v.add(id);
     session.setAttribute("readMessageVector", v);
     request.getRequestDispatcher("readMessage.jsp").include(request, response);
  }
  ```
- Finally: The external **readMessage** jsp file looks like this:

  ```
  <p>
     Text: ${readMessageVector[0]}
  </p>
  <p>
     ID:   ${readMessageVector[1]}
  </p>
  ```

  **My questions**
- Is this solution good enough to solve this problem - loading external jsp that has dynamic content ?
- Is there a better solution ? such as putting all DIVs elements in the same file instead of loading them from an external file , and showing or hiding those elements using javascript/jquery in the same file ? In this way , I will only use the JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems fine to me. If you start to make lots of different AJAX calls in the future, you would be better returning a lightweight response such as JSON from the jsps - this will save bandwidth and jQuery can be used to generate the bulky HTML markup.

Comment: Thanks @Finbarr, but if I return JSON , I think it is difficult to build the HTML elements dynamically.am I right ? what about showing and hiding DIV elements in the same file instead of loading external divs?

Comment: Building the HTML elements dynamically is very easy. Typically, with jQuery, something like $('<div></div>').insertAfter() or .insertBefore() or .appendTo() or .prependTo(), and you can chain up the method calls to add your content inside the div before it is inserted.